# Spring Security CSRF Training mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an existing Spring WebMVC application with spring security enabled. Now I want to enable Spring-Security CSRF check.

But I want to let it run in a training-mode. So the CSRF-Filter should only log any missing CSRF-Token so that it can be implemented from time to time.

Is there such a training mode in Spring-Security for CSRF-Handling?

I tried to implement a custom `org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler` and set it in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyCustomAccessDeniedHandler());
```

But unfortunately the Request does not suceed because the filter-chain stops.

I think I have to implement a custom `CsrfFilter`, but how can i set it?

Is there a easy way to implement a training mode?
Any suggestions or pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `CsrfFilter` is `final`, overriding or wrapping it is next to impossible.

However, there may be several options to achieve some sort of training mode - all with certain drawbacks and possible security issues. So be careful with that.

Here's one possible solution:

1. Providing a custom `CsrfFilter#accessDeniedHandler` [AccessDeniedHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/AccessDeniedHandler.html) that handles any missing/invalid tokens by throwing a custom exception
2. Using a custom Filter right before the `CsrfFilter` to handle/log the custom exception and continuing the chain

Here's what it could look like:

```
class MissingCsrfTokenException extends RuntimeException {
}

/**
 * Post process the CsrfFilter to use a custom AccessDeniedHandler
 */
@Component
class CsrfFilterBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof CsrfFilter) {
            CsrfFilter csrfFilter = (CsrfFilter) bean;
            csrfFilter.setAccessDeniedHandler(new AccessDeniedHandler() {

                /**
                 * Default CsrfFilter AccessDeniedHandler implementation (org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler)
                 */
                AccessDeniedHandler delegate = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

                @Override
                public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

                    // test whether the request requires a valid CsrfToken (or is in training mode)
                    boolean inTrainingMode = ...
                    if (inTrainingMode) {
                        throw new MissingCsrfTokenException();
                    } else {
                        // delegate to the default AccessDeniedHandler
                        delegate.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}

/**
 * Custom Filter that logs the token-exceptions and continues the chain.
 */
class PreCsrfFilterFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PreCsrfFilterFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (MissingCsrfTokenException ex) {
            // log and continue the filter chain
            logger.warn("No CSRF-Token found for {}", request.getRequestURI());
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                // add the custom filter before the CsrfFilter
                .addFilterBefore(new PreCsrfFilterFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solution works for me. I especially like the "trick" with catching the Exception within the filter-chain. Thank you also for pointing me to the `BeanPostProcessor`. I wasn't aware of this. In my opinion this is more clean to change the `AccessDeniedHandler` only for the `CsrfFilter` than doing it globally as I was trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Glad I could help!